# Python or expression on exception

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
try:
    info_model = Doc2Vec.load('models/info_model')
    salary_model = Doc2Vec.load('models/salary_model')
    education_model = Doc2Vec.load('models/education_model')
    experience_model = Doc2Vec.load('models/experience_model')
    skills_model = Doc2Vec.load('models/skills_model')
except:
    info_model = lrn.info_model()
    salary_model = lrn.salary_model()
    education_model = lrn.education_model()
    experience_model = lrn.experience_model()
    skills_model = lrn.skills_model()
```

Basically, it checks if the file exists and creates it if not. But for correct work I would like to check every of this variables one by one. For that I would need to use try/except to each one separately.

I came up with sth like this:

```
experience_model = Doc2Vec.load('models/experience_model') or lrn.experience_model()
```

But this line still gives me FileNotFound exception. Is there a workaround? or should I do try/exception statement for each variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a helper like this:

```py
def load_or_default(filename, default):
    try:
        return Doc2Vec.load(filename)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return default()

info_model = load_or_default('models/info_model', lrn.info_model)
salary_model = load_or_default('models/salary_model', lrn.salary_model)
education_model = load_or_default('models/education_model', lrn.education_model)
experience_model = load_or_default('models/experience_model', lrn.experience_model)
skills_model = load_or_default('models/skills_model', lrn.skills_model)
```

It's worth noting how the `default` object is only called within the function.

Comment: Since the names of the attributes of the `lrn` module match those after `models/`, you can just have the `except` clause return something like `getattr(lrn, filename.rsplit('/')[-1])()` and thus remove the second argument of the function altogether.

Comment: @ForceBru Technically yes, but that's a little bit too much magic for my tastes.